# When did the Charismatic Movement start?

Tags: christianity, protestant-church

When did the christian [Charismatic Movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charismatic_Movement) start?

Comment: If you get no luck here at *History.se* after say, a few days, you can try *Christianity.se*. They aren't as reluctant to give honest historical information as you might think.

Comment: @ LateralFractal so i came here :)

Comment: @Deekey: Is there any reason you are unhappy with the answer you get when Googling, or from Wikipedia?

Comment: i dont know who has so much pblm in this Question

Comment: If this question is off topic for History.SE then can a moderator move it to Christianity.SE please? It's perfectly on topic there and it would make a great addition.

Answer (score 3):

The [Charismatic movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azusa_Street_Revival)<sup>1</sup> began on April 3, 1960 when an Episcopalian priest, [Dennis J. Bennett](http://www.revival-library.org/pensketches/am_pentecostals/parham.html), told his congregation that he had experienced the Baptism of the Holy Spirit.<sup>2</sup> His sermon sparked a new Pentecostal revival and lead to many churches adopting some of the beliefs and practices of Pentecostal Christians. However, unlike the first major Pentecostal revival, the Azusa Street Revival in Los Angeles California, the Charismatic movement tended to stay within the mainline denominations.

<sup>1</sup> Charismatic means gifts and refers to spiritual gifts especially speaking in tongues.

<sup>2</sup> The Baptism of the Holy spirit is what Pentecostal and Charismatic Christians call the powerful spiritual experience that can include speaking in tongues.